# How to use localstorage for edit using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I did coding for `create,save,update,delete` successfully. How to use localstorage for this? edit popup is not working.

Below is my code,

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>KANNA</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/ngstorage/0.3.6/ngStorage.min.js"></script>
    <div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
        <input type="button" value="Save" ng-click="Save()" />
        <input type="button" value="Get" ng-click="Get()" />
        <input type ="button" value="Edit"ng-click="Edit()"/>
    </div>
     <script >
        var app = angular.module('MyApp', ["ngStorage"])
        app.controller('MyController', ['$scope','$localStorage','$sessionStorage','$window',function ($scope, $localStorage, $sessionStorage, $window) {
            $scope.Save = function () {
                $localStorage.templateUrl ="prakash.html";
                $sessionStorage.SessionMessage = "SessionStorage: hai.";
            }
            $scope.edit=function(){
                'prakash.html';
            }
            $scope.Get = function () {
                $window.alert($localStorage.templateUrl+ "\n" + $sessionStorage.SessionMessage);
            }
        }]);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What do you do exactly ?
I don't understand your problem ?

If you want to use a pop-up you could see [here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) in modal section